# How can I get my countdown timer, to stop starting over every time i refresh in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi guys thank you for your time , and sorry i'm kind of new.
So i have this JavaScript file in my html work ,its suppose to be a countdown (kind of timer ) .
i want it to be ( the time left till 3 June ) but i allays get the same result or not result at all . every time i refresh the browser the counter start again .I been looking videos on YouTube to try to find a way to change that but it only get worst . i have looking to other question here too but the answers are always a different code i would like to know if i can modify this one to do so 
pleas don't be to hard on me i only have 32 points i don't want to lose my right to vote and down vote 
,this is the code and thanks in advance .

```
<html>
<body>
    <head>
    </head>
        <div id="countdown">
            <div id='tiles'></div>
                <div class="labels">
                    <li>Days</li>
                    <li>Hours</li>
                    <li>Mins</li>
                    <li>Secs</li>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <script>/*---------------Getcountdown------------------*/ 
        var target_date = new Date().getTime() + (1000*3600*772); // set the 
        countdown date
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units

        var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element

        getCountdown();

        setInterval(function () { getCountdown(); }, 1000);

        function getCountdown(){

            // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
            var current_date = new Date().getTime();
            var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

            days = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 86400) );
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

            hours = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 3600) );
            seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

            minutes = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 60) );
            seconds = pad( parseInt( seconds_left % 60 ) );

            // format countdown string + set tag value
            countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours 
       + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>"; 
        }

        function pad(n) {
            return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are using `getTime()` (the current time) to calculate the end date. If you are wanting to set a specific date create the date using that date information, ie month,day,year,hour,min, etc

Comment: I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` because of `countdown date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date you're counting down to is always being incremented whenever the page loads, because it's initialized to the current time plus an offset:

```
var target_date = new Date().getTime() + (1000*3600*772)
```

Use an absolute date instead of a relative time:

```
var target_date = new Date('June 3 2018');
// or
var target_date = new Date(2018, 6, 3);
```

Comment: Patrick Evans was right about the source of the problem . but your answer realy solve the problem thank you very much , the first one var_date = change all the css and it was kind of ugly but the second one you post was just perfect . thank you very much i hope it would help more people

Answer (score 1):

Because the target_date variable is Dynamic so the countdown will always be the same.

The first line to:

```
var target_date = new Date("01,06,2018").getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, note that you have several errors in your code; and there are also some improvements that can be done to improve the question as well:

- The HTML is not valid.
- The target date is being initialized with the current time plus a constant offset into the future -- so you always see the same counter at every refresh.
- The scope of several variables can be reduced -- always a good idea.
- No need for `pad` to show the problem of your code (always strive for minimal examples).
- As a general rule, you should avoid adding elements using `innerHTML` -- if you manage to do so, you will be able to use `textContent` to just edit the contents of existing elements.
- The timer should be at least as low as half of that of the smallest time increment (in this case, a second) -- otherwise you will miss updates (i.e. you will see jumps in time that skip one full second).

A simplified, corrected version of your snippet is:

```js
function getCountdown() {
  let target_date = new Date("June 3, 2018");
  let current_date = new Date();
  let seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

  let days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

  let hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

  let minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
  let seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

  document.getElementById("tiles").textContent =
    days + " days, " +
    hours + " hours, " +
    minutes + " minutes and " +
    seconds + " seconds";
}

setInterval(function() {
  getCountdown();
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="tiles"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much is so much clean , also i just saw the time jumps, it will help i will change my code to this one look so much better and thank you for the tips , i'm trying to ask better questions since stack overflow told me to do so or they will be blocked